# gnuplot-iostream example does not compile with c11

Tags: c++11, gnuplot

I modified the Makefile to add -std=c++11 and -stdlib=libc++ to the CXXFLAGS & LDFLAGS variables and it stopped compiling with the following error:

```
$ make
c++ -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -c example-misc.cc -o example-misc.o
c++ -o example-misc example-misc.o -lutil -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::seek(long, std::__1::ios_base::seekdir)", referenced from:
  std::__1::fpos<__mbstate_t> boost::iostreams::detail::seek_device_impl<boost::iostreams::any_tag>::seek<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink>(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink&, long, std::__1::ios_base::seekdir, unsigned int) in example-misc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [example-misc] Error 1
```

Anybody knows how to fix this?

**Edit**
Problem solved by reinstalling boost with c11 flags:

```
brew reinstall boost --with-c++11
```

Comment: Have you installed boost library (http://www.boost.org/)? Is it x86_64?

Comment: I've solved the problem - I installed boost without c11. brew reinstall boost --with-c++11 did the trick.

Comment: @AnotherUser you should make that an answer and accept it instead of putting it in the question.